# Automapper with custom lazy loading objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a `Person` class which contains a property that lazy loads (custom made lazy loading) the person address data through accessing the `Item` property. I would want it to be mapped to a POCO class. How could it be done?

In addition, is it possible to be mapped only if it has data (checking the `HasData` property) and mapped as `null` if there isn’t data?.
These are the source classes:

```
public class SourcePerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyLazyLoadingObject<SourceAddress> Address;
}

public class SourceAddress
{
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

This is the custom lazy loading class (simplified):

```
public class MyLazyLoadingObject<T>
{
    private int? _id;
    private T _object;

    public T Item
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_object.IsReaded)
            {
                _object.Read();
            }

            return _object;
        }
    }

    public bool HasData
    {
        get
        {
            return _id.HasValue;
        }
    }

    // Other non-relevant properties and methods 
}
```

These are the destination classes:

```
public class DestinationPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DestinationAddress Address;
}

public class DestinationAddress
{
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `ConstructUsing` or `ConvertUsing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find conventional way of setting up conversion from `MyLazyLoadingObject<T>` to `T` and then `T` to some `TDestination` without code repetition.

But custom `IObjectMapper` implementation with some manual expression building does the job.

Here is the class that builds the mapping expression:

```
public class MyLazyLoadingObjectMapper : IObjectMapper
{
    public bool IsMatch(TypePair context)
    {
        return context.SourceType.IsGenericType && context.SourceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyLazyLoadingObject<>);
    }

    public Expression MapExpression(TypeMapRegistry typeMapRegistry, IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression, Expression contextExpression)
    {
        var item = Expression.Property(sourceExpression, "Item");
        Expression result = item;
        if (item.Type != destExpression.Type)
        {
            var typeMap = configurationProvider.ResolveTypeMap(item.Type, destExpression.Type);
            result = Expression.Invoke(typeMap.MapExpression, item, destExpression, contextExpression);
        }
        // source != null && source.HasData ? result : default(TDestination)
        return Expression.Condition(
            Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.NotEqual(sourceExpression, Expression.Constant(null)),
                Expression.Property(sourceExpression, "HasData")
            ),
            result,
            Expression.Default(destExpression.Type)
        );
    }
}
```

All you need is to register it to the `MapperRegistry`:

```
AutoMapper.Mappers.MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new MyLazyLoadingObjectMapper());
```

and of course create the regular type maps (which I guess you already did):

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceAddress, DestinationAddress>();
cfg.CreateMap<SourcePerson, DestinationPerson>();
```

Comment: Excellent solution! It works as expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I've achieved it this way:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourcePerson, DestinationPerson>().ForMember(t => t.Address, o => o.MapFrom(s => (s.Address.HasData)? s.Address.Item : null));
```

Comment: What I don't like is that I need to repeat the same line for every MyLazyLoadingObject<T> property of every object (violates DRY principle!)